# Why does WebSocket event listeners work if they are registered after events are fired?

Tags: javascript, websocket, message-queue

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), the WebSocket event listeners are registered **after** the connection is created, and the process is sequential:

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    console.log('ws connected');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

How does this work if events start firing before the listeners were registered? Say, the connection opened before the `open` listener is registered, or messaged came in before the `message` listener is registered.

I would expect the events to be lost since the event listeners are not registered yet, according to the [MDN doc on Concurrency model and Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

> In web browsers, messages are added anytime an event occurs and there is an event listener attached to it. If there is no listener, the event is lost. So a click on an element with a click event handler will add a message--likewise with any other event.

I tried to add some expensive ops in between, but it seems that the `open` and `message` event listeners only trigger after all the event listeners are properly registered. Are the WebSocket features async in nature?

```
// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// expensive ops
for (var i = 5000; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log('1');
}

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    console.log('ws connected');
});

// expensive ops
for (var i = 5000; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log('2');
}

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});

// prints "1"s, then "2"s, then "ws connected", then "Message from server"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can’t add events before an object is created so they have to be afterwards. This all works because JavaScript is single-threaded and events are handled in the same thread so nothing can happen while code is running. You can delay the execution for a year and only after your code finishes will the runtime start handling any events that have arrived while it was running. The socket might not even start connecting before your code finishes.

Therefore it’s guaranteed that no events will go amiss.

Mozilla Developer Network has a good explanation of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), the “Run to Completion” talks about the nature of JS runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I understood the event handling part. Regarding the event handler, do you mean that even if the events have already been triggered, you can still attach event listeners before they are handled? Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Comment: @paradite Mozilla has quite nice explanation of the model, I’ll add a link to that

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't address my question, specifically adding event listeners after the events are triggered, as it is stated in the doc: "In web browsers, messages are added anytime an event occurs and there is an event listener attached to it. If there is no listener, the event is lost."

Comment: @paradite In your case there is a listener. Your code runs to completion before anything else can happen. If you don’t add listeners in this block, but later, then they may be lost. But if they are added in the same block it will run to completion and nothing can be lost since any side effects of your code will happen after it’s run entirely.

Comment: Do you mean `new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')` is also somehow delay until the block is executed? I thought this is synchronously executed.

Comment: @paradite I’m not sure if it will be delayed, but at least all its events will be so it would be easier to just set it into the queue to be handled after your code. This is exactly the same as for example setting a source for img tag several times in a block. Only the last value will ever be assigned to DOM and loaded, the previous values are considered like they never happened. Javascript is highly asynchronous.

Comment: @paradite the `WebSocket()` constructor is not synchronous, it attempts the socket connection asynchronously in the background. This is a requirement of the [WebSocket API](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/): "*When the `WebSocket()` constructor is invoked, the UA must run these steps: ... 7.Return a new `WebSocket` object, **and continue these steps in the background (without blocking scripts)**...*"